# resource loading in java

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I am having problem with java resource loading process.
I have a jar core-app.jar and contains a class ResourceLoader.class
which loads a file containing in another jar main-app.jar
I have put core-app.jar in java classpath` and I am running main-app.jar as

java -jar main-app.jar

main-app.jar uses ResourceLoader class from core-app.jar to read files in itself but

```
FileNotFound Exception is happening.
```

My code in ResourceLoader.clss to read file is

```
public static void readFile(String name) {
      BufferedReader reader=null;
      reader=new BufferedReader(new     
InputStreamReader(ResourceLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)));
        }
         //another method to read
        readFromReader(reader);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: What name are you passing into the readFile method?

Comment: @mikea I am passing file name which is inside of main class jar